# SSRS Returing the day of the week Using Expressions

Tags: reporting-services

I am using SSRS to return the date and it works fine "="" & DateAdd(DateInterval.Day,-1,Today()).  This returns 2/23/2014. I would like to take this one step further and use a second text box and expression to return the day of the week for the expression about.   So my results will be be

2/23/2014
 Sunday

Can this be done in one expression.  Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do that by using 'ReportItems!' This allows you to reference a value from another textbox on the report.

So if you first text box (the one that returns 2/23/2014) is called 'Textbox001' the code you would place in the second text box (where you want the weekday returned) would be:

= WeekDayName ( WeekDay( ReportItems!Textbox001.Value ) )

Hope that helps!